# LyX font size in unreadable

Tags: lyx

I install LyX but the font size in program is unreadable (screen). How can I inncrease it?[image]

Comment: if you haven't been messing with Tool > Preferences in LyX, look like a problem of the system installed fonts or system preferences. If you have Linux, check that you installed the package `fonts-lyx` or so.

Comment: Not good :( Re installation doesnt help, maybe I have to delete some files which are not deleted by LYX

Comment: Do you by chance have a HiDPI monitor? I think whenever LyX 2.4 is released (I would guess in a few months) there's a chance it will work better. I remember seeing some fixes along these lines.

Comment: Yes I have HiDpi monitor so maybe that's the reason

Answer (score -1):

Open **Preferences > Look and Feel > Screen Fonts** and play with **Default Zoom** and **Font Sizes**

Answer (score -1):

If you click in the drop down menu and type the first letter of the function you are trying to access -- "q" for quotation -- it will show that in a readable font.  Clicking just below that will then set that function.

Still, a pain.